# Call jQuery function on AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

How can I call a jQuery function or code with AngularJS?

For example, I have this HTML:

`<iframe ng-src="{{v}}"></iframe>`

And my controller:

```
angular.module("myApp", [])
  .controller("AppCtrl", function($scope, myService) {
    $scope.myScope = function() {

      $('iframe').pluginCall();

      myService.myFunc(function( data ){
        $scope.myVar = 'Hey';
        [...]
    });
   };
  });
```

So, I want to run `$('iframe').css('opacity','.5');` for the stuff that will be returned for me.

How can I do this?

[Check it!](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jbrwBg?editors=101)

Comment: don't put dom code in controllers...use directives. Element probably won't exist when you run that inside controller if using any routing templates and controllers shouldn't know anything about the dom

Comment: @charlietfl hmm, this is exactly what happens. I'll check it, thanks

Comment: if all you need is a youtube player, maybe you should search for angular modules doing exactly that. For example, a quick google search lead me to that: https://github.com/brandly/angular-youtube-embed .

Comment: @BiAiB nice, but it's not what I'm looking for. Thanks for the tip anyway

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you should do that, use the angular way instead:

```
<iframe ng-src="{{v}}" ng-style="{ opacity: '.5' }"></iframe>
```

If you really want to get the object inside the controller, you can use angular's element queries:

```
angular.element(document.querySelector('iframe')).css('opacity','.5';
```

Comment: this jquery call was just an example, but I'll do something else, but the jquery I need to do is similar, but not css stuff.

Comment: Then please include what it is for, because then we might be able to give a better solution then using jQuery, this seems like an X-Y question

Answer (score 1):

Use a directive to initialize jQuery plugins if you must use them. This assures you that element exists when plugin is initialized.

```
<iframe my-iframe>
```

JS

```
app.directive('myIframe', function(){
      return{
        link:function(scope, elem, attrs){
          // elem is a jQuery object
          elem.pluginCall();
        }
    }    
});
```

Note that for angular to use jQuery internally for `angular.element`,  you must load `jQuery.js` in page before `angular.js`

Answer (score 0):

```
angular.module("myApp", [])
.controller("AppCtrl", function($scope, myService) {
   $scope.myScope = function() {
      $(function () {
        // You can Write jquery here
        $('iframe').css('opacity','.5');
      });
      myService.myFunc(function( data ){
        $scope.myVar = 'Hey';
        [...]
     });
   };
});
```

Comment: `document.ready` is worthless in angular with a few rare exceptions. It definitely doesn't belong in controllers though. Controller will run before element even exists

Answer (score 0):

You can use stuff like this :

```
$scope.yourAngularFunction=function(){
      myService.myFunc(function( data ){
      $scope.myVar = 'Hey';
      $('iframe').css('opacity','.5');
      $('#someOtherDiv').slideUp();
      //add other jquery stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Never use `jQuery` with angular unless & until required, because whatever is available in jquery is achievable in angularjs.

Dont Include ~18kb library into your page unnecessarily, for me its more like redundant code & also performance hit.

[Think in Angular Way First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background)

*when coding a solution, first "think in AngularJS"; if you can't think of a solution, ask the community; if after all of that there is no easy solution, then feel free to reach for the jQuery. But don't let jQuery become a crutch or you'll never master AngularJS.*

---

### Pure Angular solution

**HTML CODE:**

```
<div ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testCtrllr">
<div ng-style="{'background-color': backgroundImageInfo}">
    <input type="file" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().fileThatChangeBackground(this)" />
</div>
</div>
```

**AngularJS Code:**

```
angular.module('testApp',[])
.controller('testCtrllr', function($scope){
  $scope.backgroundImageInfo='red';    
  $scope.fileThatChangeBackground = function(scope) {                    
      $scope.$apply(function(){$scope.backgroundImageInfo='blue';});
  };
});
```

[Live Demo @ JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/zxwye5oa/20/)